# unexpected power loss in double conversion ups

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, ups

I have picked up a 6kva (4000w) online ups made by MGE (now eaton). It is a used otherwise it functions correctly. The AC input and output rating is 220v. The battery pack is 240v DC the charging is 270v DC.
[Datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/82a5/0900766b8002fef7.pdf)

During Testing I found the following:

TEST1: No AC Input / Battery connected / No load : Power Consumption =100w (measured at battery)

TEST2: No AC Input / Battery connected / 800w load : Power Consumption = 900w (measured at battery)

TEST3: AC Input / Battery Connected fully charged / No load : Power Consumption =600w (measured at ac input)

TEST4: AC Input / Battery Dis-Connected / No load : Power Consumption = 550w (measured at ac input)

**Problem:** TEST4 is what is very strange to me , since i cannot think of where is the power going ,  Since Inverter consumes 100w no load, and no battery and charging losses, the rectifier loss should be dependent on load (which is almost zero) . the unit contains 2 contactors inside but I doubt they consume that much.

**Question:** Do you have an explanation for this ? is this common in this kind of UPS topology ?

Comment: How did you perform your AC power measurements?

Comment: Something is getting hot.

Comment: Another test that may be useful is better somewhat discharged, AC input, battery charging. Does power in equal approx ,550 Watt + Battery power. || It seems that the battery charger needs aboutv550 Wcjustvto turn up for work. That's about 2A at Vcharge so where it goes should be findable

Comment: "How did you measure AC power"? per other comment : did you discount reactive power (which, being reactive, is not actually consumed) from your measurements? Reactive power at 10% of rated power may or may not be perfectly normal for this product...

Comment: @brhans the AC power measurement was done by a fluke clamp meter

Comment: @user_1818839 , no i didnot discount the reactive power , actually i feel dump now . how should i calculate the real power ?

Comment: See if your AC measuring equipment can calculate power factor. Or find equipment that can. From there, separating real from reactive is simple math.